# Bind ComboBox DataTemplate to ItemSource property

Tags: wpf, data-binding, mvvm, combobox

I have a DataTemplate for a ComboBox in a GridView column. I want to display a ComboBox when the cell is being edited and a TextBlock otherwise. However I am having trouble getting the TextBox to display the desired value.

The ViewModel for the row has only RegionId but the Combo is bound to a collection of Region objects (with Id and Name). I'd like to display the Region.Name when the value is not being edited, at the moment I can only find a way to show the RegionId because the ViewModel does not contain a Name property.

I am using a Telerik combobox but I think my problem would be the same with a standard ComboBox control as I think this is just a binding issue.

How should I bind my TextBlock in the DataTemplate?

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RegionId}" />  <!-- would like Region.Name -->
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellTemplate>
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <telerik:RadComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource regionView}}" 
            DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" SelectedValue="{Binding Path=RegionId, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn.CellEditTemplate>
</telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
```

Comment: Why can't you add the Name property to your ViewModel?

Comment: Good point, I'd like to but it's specified in a data contract that is fixed.

Comment: Why don't you put Region.Name?

Comment: Because it has to be bound to the ViewModel for that row, and the ViewModel has only RegionId

Comment: You could use a converter to solve this Problem. Bind to RegionId, use your regionView as ConverterParameter and search through it in your converter.

Comment: Actually I need to correct my last comment. I CAN modify the ViewModel but what I can't do is modify the underlying object object inside it which has just RegionId (but not Name). As I mentioned in one of the answers below, I might need to think a bit about how I populate the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ViewModels are supposed to be reflected in the `View`, so your best course of action would just be to add a `Name` property to your `ViewModel`

But since you said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15762957/bind-combobox-datatemplate-to-itemsource-property#comment22405284_15762957) that your `ViewModel` is defined in a fixed data contract, you could instead use a `Converter` to convert the `Id` to the `Name`

If your converter code has access to the list of `Regions`, then it's easiest to do with an [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx)

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RegionId, Converter={StaticResource MyRegionIdToNameConverter}}" />
```

But if not, you'll have to use an [IMultiValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) to pass both parameters in

```
<TextBlock.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyRegionIdToNameMultiConverter}">
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource regionView}"/>
        <Binding Path="RegionId" />
    </MultiBinding>
</TextBlock.Text>
```

Comment: Actually, I should have been clearer. I CAN modify my row-level ViewModel but the object it refers to has only RegionId (and it's this object that I cannot modify because it's DataContract is fixed). Maybe I need to think a bit more about what I can do in the ViewModel

Comment: @openshac Why not just create a 2nd property of `RegionName` which returns something like `RegionList.First(p => p.Id == RegionId).Name`?

Comment: The requirement for this piece of work changed so I did not need to implement it in the end, but this solution looks like it would work OK.